# The SQL still inserts the data into the database even if it's wrong

Tags: php, android, mysql

What I want to do is: I am inserting a data into the database using Android. But it has to **RETRIEVE/SEARCH** for this plate number in the first table BUT before inserting the data into the other table, it should check first if there is this plate number in this table, if true then INSERT the data into the table, if wrong then don't INSERT the data into the table.

The problem that I am having is: The data that I typed in my EditText's will still **INSERT** into the database/table even though the Plate Number that I typed is wrong.

I think something is wrong with my SQL statement?

My codes in PHP:

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$db='employee101';

$PLATE_NUM = $_POST["PLATE_NUM"];
$PUV_TYPE = $_POST["PUV_TYPE"];
$content = $_POST["content"];

$sql = "select * from employee_data where PLATE_NUM like '$PLATE_NUM';";//first table where you retrieve the plate number first
$sql_insert = "insert into employee_content (PLATE_NUM, PUV_TYPE, content) values('$PLATE_NUM', '$PUV_TYPE', '$content')";//insert the table

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql_insert);
$response = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0 && ($result2)=== TRUE ){
        echo"Log-In Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
}else{
    echo "Log-In not success";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

My codes in Android Studio:

onButtonClick codes:

```
public void Button(View view) {

        String puv_plate = report_plate.getText().toString();
        String puv_type = report_type.getText().toString();
        String content = report_content.getText().toString();
        String type="report";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, puv_plate,puv_type,content);
    }
```

Background Worker class:

```
if(type.equals("report")){
                try {
                    String id_ret = params[1];
                    String puv_type = params[2];
                    String report = params[3];

                    URL url = new URL(retrieve_id);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("PLATE_NUM","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_ret,"UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("PUV_TYPE", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(puv_type, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("content", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(report, "UTF-8");;
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Check my updated answer, pretty sure that's the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this statement in your php looks sketchy:

$sql = "select * from employee_data where PLATE_NUM like '$PLATE_NUM';"

I thought the like keyword finds a pattern[1]. Why not do = there? Cause your if statement = true only if both conditions are true, and if a pattern is found in PLATE_NUM column, it will always be true. You want a specific plate number to be the conditional check.

$sql = "select * from employee_data where PLATE_NUM = '$PLATE_NUM';"

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Edit, problem is here, you are always running the result2 query even before the if statement checks. You need to only run result2 when result1 returns success.

change it to

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

// comment this out $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql_insert);
    $response = array();

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0 ){
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql_insert);
```

Comment: I changed it to '=' but it still inserts to the database.

Comment: Ah I see your problem now, you will ALWAYS run result2. I am updating my answer, it's updated now

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two way

> 1) check manually in the database using some php script. Then you can insert the data.
>   the logic for this is

write onesql query to check the count `where the PLATE_NUM='the value'`

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROm table_name WHERE PLATE_NUM='the value';"
```

Then get thecount value from the result. If the value is greater than the 0. means the value already exist in the database

```
if($count>0){
    echo "PLATE_NUM already exist";
    // if you want to update. Here you can update.
}else{
    // perform your actions like insert.
}
```

> 2)Make the `PLATE_NUM` field as unique key in the databadse.. The this will automatically checks for the duplication

Fetching count using mysqli_bind parameter concept

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");
$stmt->bind_param('d', $plate_no_value);// here d for number and s for string 
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: AM i doing this right? $count = mysqli_query($con, $query);?

Comment: yeahh for better practice i have edited the answer with MySQLi_bind parameter concept. Please have a look at that

Answer (score 1):

Actually, You wrote the query but you didn't check that the first query whether it's available or not without checking you inserted the data,

Instead, you can simply use one `UPDATE` query to achieve this,

```
$sql_insert = "UPDATE employee_content SET PLATE_NUM = '$PLATE_NUM', PUV_TYPE = '$PUV_TYPE', content = '$content' WHERE PLATE_NUM='$PLATE_NUM' )";
```